# backspace does not remove tput command's underline in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, tput

i'm trying to practice to do a nice and neat interface. However, i'm stuck at this problem. I'm trying to underline the input of the user which i managed to do it using this method

```
echo -n "Title : "; read -p "$(tput smul)" getTitle; tput rmul
```

`tput smul` is used to underline the word while `tput rmul` is used to remove the underline after this statement is successful.

Unfortunately, when i accidentally typed wrongly and decided to back space, the underline did not disappear accordingly.

Instead, the underline remains there even though i removed all the user input.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`readline`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) via the `-e` flag:

```
echo -n "Title : "; read -ep "$(tput smul)" getTitle; tput rmul
```

Comment: thanks! it works but may i ask what does the `-e` flag do?

Comment: It tells `read` to use the `readline` library to read the line. Check the Wikipedia article I've linked.